# Best way to automatically format timestamps to just include date(Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, date-format

I've been struggling with creating a way to extract just the date from a timestamp coming from a Google Form response. I use the date to pull specific cells I need on other tabs and it doesn't seem to work with time stamps.

I've tried good ol Format>Number>Date but the formatting of column gets overwritten every time a new response comes in. Anyone have a solution to this? Heres the link to the sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rI_AwTy2teUeojF7yKFyeb8BEC0uju8slCjEspgysEI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What does the timestamp look like? Something like 2018-07-1T18:30:37.000Z?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of date related formulas you can use. Check out the [reference documents.](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en&ref_topic=1361471)

You could use [`DATEDIF()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055612?hl=en). For example, `IF(DATEDIF("4/7/2018 17:21:21", "4/7/2018 19:52:49", "D")=0, TRUE, FALSE)`.

You could also use a combination of `DAY()`, `MONTH()`, `YEAR()`.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found for this is to create another date column in the form response sheet. I use `ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(A2:A))` in the 2nd row of that column. This gives you the date only format for the default timestamp and each new entry will automatically update this column since it's a dynamically built array.